# TabLayout | TabIndicator Unselected Color

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I am working with `TabLayout`

I need to set the color of TabIndicator when its not selected.

This is what i need to do -

[image]

This is what i have done -

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `app:tabTextColor`for this .

- When  **Unselected** it will show  `app:tabTextColor`
- When **Selected** it will show `app:tabSelectedTextColor`

Use below code :

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
    app:tabTextColor="#AAAAAA"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/NavigationTabTextAppeareance"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    >
```

**styles.xml :** for **bold** Tabtext

```
 <style name="NavigationTabTextAppeareance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

For **Unselected** Tab bottom color :

Reference:  [TabLayout color of unselected tab underline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45580036/tablayout-color-of-unselected-tab-underline)

Comment: I need to change the line color when its not selected.

Comment: Look into this @ShoebSiddique  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45580036/tablayout-color-of-unselected-tab-underline

Comment: Ok Let me check...

Answer (score 0):

you can set like this using tabtextColor  for default color when tab not selected

create xml  in drawable underlinedrawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <!-- UNSELECTED TAB STATE -->
<item android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false">
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <!-- Bottom indicator color for the UNSELECTED tab state -->
        <item android:top="-5dp" android:left="-5dp" android:right="-5dp">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <stroke android:color="#65acee" android:width="2dp"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
</selector>
```

To change the tabtextColor Underline add the underlinedrawable in main xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/unselected_color"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/selected_color"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/underlinedrawable" />
```

Comment: I need to change the line color when its not selected.

Comment: @ShoebSiddique see the edit ans

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/45582178/8089770

Comment: @ tried this code, but it is not working.

Comment: @VishvaDave yeah i know  will keep in mind next time :)

Comment: @Bunny give reference never copy paste

Comment: @VishvaDave yup sure